# "folgende" or "Folgendes"?

Tags: usage, declension, inflection

I am writing test instructions for a website.
Which is (more) correct from these two sentences?

> Die Testanweisung ist Folgendes:
>
> Die Testanweisung ist folgende:

I know that it is *die Testanweisung*, so that speaks for *folgende* being correct. Intuitively, however, *Folgendes* sounds better to me, but I am not a native speaker of German.

Comment: I'd just write "Testanweisung:".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is, if 'folgend' is used as a noun or as an adverb.

Is it 'das Folgende' or 'die folgende Erklärung'?

So your options are

> Die Testanweisung ist Folgendes, *das was folgt*:

or

> Die Testanweisung ist folgende, *Anweisung, die folgt*:

As a reference, check out the Duden entry for [folgend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/folgend) and [Regel 72](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K72) for capitalization of adjectives and participles.

Comment: Thank you! +1 for the link to [Regel 72](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K72).

Answer (score 2):

"Die" Anweisung, also **folgende**